# Converting from TASM to NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, tasm

I'm very new to assembly. I'm trying to rewrite code from tasm to nasm.
Is it very complicated? Code isn't long, about 200 lines.

Will you suggest some useful links like http://left404.com/2011/01/04/converting-x86-assembly-from-masm-to-nasm-3/?

Or help please help with converting:

```
.model small ;;  -> ?
.data        ;;  -> section .data
.stack       ;;  -> ?
.code        ;;  -> section .text
delay proc   ;;  -> ?
delay endp   ;;  -> ?
```

Am I right in that is written and what will be the solution to other problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I found NOMYSO, it's a MASM and NASM to TASM converter, but it requires the use of DOS Operating system. EDIT: It also does TASM/MASM to NASM.
 http://www.devoresoftware.com/nomyso/

Comment: Didn't you ask for a converter before you edited your question?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I  understood your answer mistakenly at first time i read that!
Thanks!